# How to use statsmodels' Granger causality test to measure the lag between two time series?

Tags: time-series, python

I am using the Granger causality test to measure the lag between pairs of time series where it is already apparent that one is following the other. So I am not expecting this test to tell me whether causality is likely or not, but rather to help me measure what the lag is.

The question is: is my method for sorting the lag hypothesis optimal? The measurement yields a sensible result for most cases, but there are a few where the result is a counter-intuitive and very long lag.

In the following I will first describe my method and then show two examples, one where my method works and one where it does not.

**The method:**
I am using [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/index.html), which comes with a [Granger-test module](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests.html). In my method I run the Granger test for lags between 1 and 12 days. Then I look at the values from the F-test. The lag with the highest F-test value is the optimal lag. Here is the code in Python:

```
granger_test_result = grangercausalitytests(data[:, 1::-1], maxlag=12, verbose=False)

optimal_lag = -1
F_test = -1.0
for key in granger_test_result.keys():
    _F_test_ = granger_test_result[key][0]['params_ftest'][0]
    if _F_test_ > F_test:
        F_test = _F_test_
        optimal_lag = key
return optimal_lag
```

**Example #1:**
This figure illustrates the kind of data I am analyzing. It is evident that green series follows the orange one. In this case, my method works pretty fine and the optimal lag is found to be 1 day.

[image: two time series with a lag, as determined via the Granger causality test, of 1 day]

**Example #2:**
In this case, my method yields a counter-intuitive and very large lag of 12 days.

[image]

This is the output from statsmodels F-test for each of the tested lags. The first item in the tuple corresponds to the F-test value. The highest value is indeed for 12L.

```
Optimal lag 12. F_test: 74.84. p_value: 0.00
(32.153600306648876, 4.9523452120563632e-07, 57.0, 1L)
(51.600830587070561, 2.9531736086260536e-13, 54.0, 2L)
(46.061291459709828, 1.511140176815108e-14, 51.0, 3L)
(34.512420150659764, 1.4224612929215072e-13, 48.0, 4L)
(22.215895296628979, 3.7705907562143266e-11, 45.0, 5L)
(18.817209069293003, 1.7380007128923565e-10, 42.0, 6L)
(14.366562461309808, 4.6093266266687769e-09, 39.0, 7L)
(11.296513565933811, 7.9114754208643629e-08, 36.0, 8L)
(12.008824010113649, 3.9713072573193326e-08, 33.0, 9L)
(10.237915003417235, 3.1897816507786703e-07, 30.0, 10L)
(9.7564732369412628, 8.1924196528108249e-07, 27.0, 11L)
(74.843204319602407, 5.2948535623699612e-16, 24.0, 12L)
```

Comment: Why don't you look at autocorrelation (ACF) and partial autocorrelation (PACF) instead? They are direct measures of lead-lag relationships while Granger causality is indirect at best and irrelevant at worst (depending on the properties of the series).

Comment: Are you sure that this is actually a use-case for  for Granger causality? Correct me if I am wrong, but suppose you have a set of time series that it cointegrated, doesn't there exist some theorem that says something about one Granger causing another?

Answer (score 2):

Lag length selection in Granger Causality tests is usually based on information criteria (AIC, BIC, etc.) instead of an F-test comparison. But Granger Causality seems not to be the adequate concept for your purpose to "measure what the lag is". Applying model selection criteria (e.g. information criteria) in Granger causality tests does not tell you what "the" lag is, but rather looks for the number of lags, such that the last added lag of one variable still improves the prediction of the other variable.

Answer (score 0):

to solve the problem "correlation does not necessarily imply causation" --
[Granger Causality Test in Python](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/granger-causality-test-in-python/) is used & shows if *X & its lags* are forecasting *Y*, meaning X & Y to be Cause & Effect, - so the essence: fitting [VAR](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304594/interpretation-of-granger-test-outputs-in-r). But not analysing lags of one timeseries (e.g. X). In order to measure what the lag is in one timeseries you should see Autocorrelation factor.

More precise ([here](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/granger-causality-test/)):"We only test if X (and lags of X) is helpful in explaining Y, and thereby help forecasting it. So we are not concerned about the true causal relationship between the variables. ". And important: ts_s should be stationary, meaning mean & var not changing in time

[There](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.html#grangercausalitytests) are [4 tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75148401/15893581) for granger non causality of 2 time series, aiming to hypothesis of causality testing ([interpretation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/477824/347139)) -- & can apply either all of them or any - for approving your [conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56360565/15893581) done

> H0 : X does not granger cause Y,  H1 : X does granger cause Y,  if
> p-value > 0.05 then H0 is accepted